# How to get the WordPress post thumbnail (featured image) URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I am using this function to get the featured images:

```
<a href="#" rel="prettyPhoto">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
</a>
```

Now I want to get the full featured image on click on the anchor tag for which I need a featured image URL in

```
<a href="here" rel="prettyPhoto">
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 368, accepted):

Check the code below and let me know if it works for you.

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
  <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
  <div id="custom-bg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">

  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thank u very much it is work . i want to add also condition.  like if have post thumbail then show this and if not then another div or css or default image any idea how

Comment: i made it but it is correct way or not i don't know. `<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
<div class="section bannerarea cashstudybanner" style="background-image: url(
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
echo $image[0];
} else { ?>
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/common-banner.jpg
<?php } ?>
)">`

Comment: Thank you very much! This code is working perfectly.

Comment: Just thought I'd drop by to say I use this answer all the time. It's downright comical that almost a full decade after this post wordpress still hasn't simplified this dramatically.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This code works with the user logged, but the user not logged in the image is null. Any suggestion for my problem. I using WP 5.7

Answer (score 118):

If you want JUST the source, and not an array with other information:

```
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
```

Comment: For version 4.4.0 and up `wp_get_attachment_image_url()`.

Comment: this was exactly what I needed. loads full img src. thank you!

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_image_url` is only applicable if you know the attachment ID (not post ID).

Answer (score 23):

```
// Try it inside loop.  
<?php
$feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
echo $feat_image;
?>
```

Comment: @gavard.e would **actually** work with `"` instead of `'` :P But the quotes are not necessary at all.

Answer (score 20):

This perfectly worked for me:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'thumbnail'); ?>
```

Comment: Note: Only available since Wordpress 4.4.0

Comment: <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id); ?>
If you want the full size image.

Answer (score 19):

Easy way!

```
 <?php 
     wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()))
 ?>
```

Answer (score 11):

I think this is the easiest solution and the updated one:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('single-post-thumbnail'); ?>
```

Comment: The one that is at the top didn't work (without PHP errors, which I didn't want as I'm building a WordPress theme for the masses) but this one did. +1

Answer (score 8):

You can try this:

```
<?php 
    $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); 
    echo $feat_image; 
?>
```

Comment: this only print: '$feat_image';

Comment: my mistake its, echo $feat_image;

Answer (score 8):

This is the simplest answer:

```
<?php
    $img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postID, 'post-thumbnail');
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this one

```
<?php 
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); 
?>
```

Comment: Use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` if you want the image URL only.

Answer (score 5):

I had searched a lot and found nothing, until I got this:

`<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( null, 'full' ); ?>`

Which simply give you the full image URL without the entire `<img>` tag.

Hope that can help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can also get the URL for image attachments as follows. It works fine.

```
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium'); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

```
<?php
   $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
?>
<a href="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also get it from post_meta like this:

```
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured_image', true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You will try this

```
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full'); ?> // Here you can manage your image size like medium, thumbnail, or custom size
    <img src="<?php echo $url ?>" 
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply inside the loop write `<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>` as shown below:-

```
$args=array('post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type_slug','order' => 'DESC','posts_per_page'=> -1) ;
$the_qyery= new WP_Query($args);

if ($the_qyery->have_posts()) :
    while ( $the_qyery->have_posts() ) : $the_qyery->the_post();?>

<div class="col col_4_of_12">
    <div class="article_standard_view">
        <article class="item">
            <div class="item_header">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="Post"></a>
            </div>

        </article>
    </div>
</div>            
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to fetch full image size from post thumbnail you can use this code.

```
$img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'full');
<img src="<?PHP echo $img_url?> ">
```

here, get_the_ID() is post id.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ):
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the post is an image and we already know what the image is, it's possible to get the thumbnail URL without too much hassle:

```
echo pathinfo($image->guid, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the URL for image attachments as follows:

```
<?php
    "<div><a href=".get_permalink(id).">".wp_get_attachment_url(304, array(50,50), 1)."</a></div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php 
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail_size');

    $feature_image_url = $image_src[0]; 
?>
```

You can change the `thumbnail_size` value as per your required size.

Answer (score 0):

You can get image src for specific size by `wp_get_attachment_url` function.

```
<?php 
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); 
?>
<img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "mabp_thumbnail_url", true); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width ="100%" height ="" />
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?