# how to show a featured image in wordpress using the $wpdb class

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get posts from an external website to show on my own website and I am simply achieving this with the wordpress `$wpdb` class.

I have managed to display the titles of the posts from the external website on to my website however, I am having trouble displaying the featured image that is associated with it's own post.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

$mydb = new wpdb('root','','test','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results(" select post_title, guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = '21' ");
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($rows as $obj) : ?>

    <li><a href="http://localhost/database2/2015/11/26/<?php echo $obj->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $obj->post_title; ?></a></li>
    <?php echo $obj->meta_value; ?>
<?php
endforeach;
echo '</ul>'; 
?>
```

Comment: How are you getting the posts? Connecting direct to the database? Using an API?

Comment: no, i am using the wordpress built in class $wpdb to connect to the database

Comment: There are so many examples available.  Can't you find one.
     `echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'thumbnail' );`.  Please refer here.  Don't make your code complicated.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261883/how-to-get-wordpress-post-featured-image-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the associated featured image for a post from the external database using the following SQL query below:

```
    "SELECT
    p1.*,
    wm2.meta_value
FROM
wp_posts p1
LEFT JOIN
    wp_postmeta wm1
    ON (
    wm1.post_id = p1.id
    AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
    AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
    )
LEFT JOIN
wp_postmeta wm2
ON (
    wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
    AND wm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
    AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL
)
WHERE
    p1.post_status= %s
    AND p1.post_type=%s
ORDER BY
    p1.post_date DESC
 LIMIT 4", 'publish','post'));
```