# Set featured image as post background-image

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have set my front page to show the 5 most recent posts from a particular category. I have set the posts to be 100% of the view width/height and I would like each post's background-image to be the featured-image chosen by the user or a default. I appear to have set the default correctly, but if I set a featured image on the test posts, the post background is white.

Here is the code I have made from index.php:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> 
         style= "background-image: 
             <?php
                 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                     the_post_thumbnail('full');
                 } else {
                     ?>url(http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/background.png)"
             <?php 
                 }
             ?> 
>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `the_post_thumbnail()` returns an image tag, not the image src. You'll want to [get the featured image URL instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261883/how-to-get-wordpress-post-featured-image-url).

Comment: Achieved! Thank you!