# Display latest wordpress featured images on static html page

Tags: html, wordpress, display, wordpress-featured-image

I have a wordpress blog page installed in subfolder of my website(converted from html)and a static html home page. 
**I would like to display 3 latest posts and its featured images on home page.** With code below i can display latest posts text but **i dont know how to show featured images of posts.**  Into index.php of a wordpress custom theme i placed featured photo inside a div:

```html
<div id="blogphoto"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
```

This is the code on static html index.php page which is pulling out latest post. Can anyone help me to get featured images of these posts too?

```html
<div id="wp-post">

      <?php
      
      $args = array('numberposts'=>1);
      $recent_posts=wp_get_recent_posts($args);
      foreach( $recent_posts as $recent_post ){
      echo "<h3>".$recent_post['post_title']."</h3> <br>"; 
      echo "<span>".$recent_post['post_date']."</span> <br>";
      echo  "<p>".$recent_post['post_content']."</p><br><br>";
      
      }
      ?>
     </div>
    
    <div id="wp-post2">
    <?php
    
    $args = array('numberposts'=>1 , 'offset'=>1 );
    $recent_posts=wp_get_recent_posts($args);
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent_post ){ 
    echo "<span>".$recent_post['post_title']."</span> <br>";
    echo  "<p>".$recent_post['post_content']."</p><br><br>";
    }

    ?>
    </div>

    <div id="wp-post3">
    <?php
    
    $args = array('numberposts'=>1 , 'offset'=>2 );
    $recent_posts=wp_get_recent_posts($args);
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent_post ){ 
    echo "<span>".$recent_post['post_title']."</span> <br>";
    echo  "<p>".$recent_post['post_content']."</p><br><br>";
    }

    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get WordPress post featured image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261883/how-to-get-wordpress-post-featured-image-url)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to this code `the_post_thumbnail` getting the feature image

```
<?php
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $i = 1;
    while($query->have_posts()) { 
        echo '<div id="wp-post-'.$i.'">';
        $query->the_post();
        ?><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // only print out the thumbnail if it actually has one
            echo '<p>post says it has a featured image</p>'; // double checking
            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
        } else {
            echo '<p>this post does not have a featured image</p>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        $i++;
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>no posts found</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I copied you code under <div id="wp-post"> but i got error:Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function have_posts() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SajtKomunalca/index.php:140 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SajtKomunalca/index.php on line 140. Can you please tell me more precisely where to copy your code and how to combine it with mine?